# Evento unload de JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Buenas noches: Estoy diseñando un sistema donde coloco fragmentos de diseño HTML con el evento load de JQuery de la siguiente forma:

```
$('.viewrunner-panel').load('../modules/runners/runnersView.php', { "idRunner": id });
```

EL evento load lo utilizo para "incrustar" cada vista que necesite para el CRUD, listados con datatable, ingresos, modificación y eliminación de registros, etc. En la medida en que utilizo el evento, se me va llenando de código el index, lo que deseo hacer es utilizar cada vista y luego "descargarla", es decir, que no aparezca en el diseño del index.
En la documentación de JQuery aparece el evento unload el cual debo utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
$('.viewrunner-panel').trigger('unload');
```

Pero no me está funcionando. ¿Existe otra forma de realizar ésta operación?

Comment: Creo que deberías usar `.on( "unload", handler )` pues `.trigger('unload')` sería para invocar el evento, no para ejecutar tu código en el. Deberías poner algo más de código que nos ayude a entender como lo estas haciendo. Mira la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y pon un [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) funcional o al menos más detallado.

Comment: A parte de lo que dice @Fly también puedes hacer algo sencillo```$('.viewrunner-panel').html("")```

Comment: Fly el evento $('.viewrunner-panel').trigger('unload');, según entiendo por la información de la página de JQuery, debería hacer lo que necesito: "vaciar" el código HTML que acabo de cargar con el evento load en el div con la clase viewrunner-panel. Yo pensé que así como existe un evento "load" también había un evento "unload". Acabo de probar con la opción que me dió christian (html("")) y funcionó, eliminó todo el código que había cargado.

Comment: La [descripción de unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) dice: `Bind an event handler to the "unload" JavaScript event`. Y la [descripción de load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) es : `Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.` Por lo tanto no son funciones complementarias, aunque su nombre induzca a creerlo.